# How to stop scrolling in general on iOS for Chrome or Safari - CSS/ JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created an input element, which contains a click eventlistener, that when it fires it runs a function, that makes an element visible by the css rule "display:block;".

This element contains the following rules:

```
.elementExample
{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-overflow: hidden;
}
```

In a few words, this element comes at the top of everything else, as I want this input element to be at the top of the mobile screen, as it runs an autocomplete function, for showing results that the user has to select.

Everything works great, I managed to do it, however what I am struggling is to make in iOS chrome and safari to stop any sort of scrolling on the entire page and only have a scrolling option within the results only, as when the user is in focus on an input box, the user can scroll down freely. This happens, only while the user is in focus. This is the relevent coding I tried to do it with:

```
html .inputHighlightText:focus
{
    overflow: hidden!important;
    -webkit-overflow: hidden!important;
    -moz-overflow: hidden!important;
    -o-overflow: hidden!important;
    -ms-overflow: hidden!important;
}

    this.preventDefault = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if (e.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
            }


            this.disable_scroll_mobile = function(el = null){
                if(el !== null) {
                    $(el).focus((e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }

                $("body").css("overflow", "hidden!important");
                $("#fullScreenBg").css("overflow", "hidden!important");
                $(window).css("overflow", "hidden!important");
                window.addEventListener('touchmove',$self.preventDefault, false);
                document.addEventListener('touchmove',$self.preventDefault, false);
                window.addEventListener('scroll',$self.preventDefault, false);
                document.addEventListener('scroll',$self.preventDefault, false);
            }

            this.enable_scroll_mobile = function(){
                $("body").css("overflow", "scroll");
                $("#fullScreenBg").css("overflow", "scroll");
                $(window).css("overflow", "scroll");
                window.removeEventListener('touchmove',$self.preventDefault, false);
                document.removeEventListener('touchmove',$self.preventDefault, false);
                window.removeEventListener('scroll',$self.preventDefault, false);
                document.removeEventListener('scroll',$self.preventDefault, false);
            }
this.disable_scroll_mobile();
```

I tried everything. How do I stop iOS users from scrolling while they are in focus on input, unless if they scroll on the list that appears?

Answer (score 0):

"all devices except iOS respect the `overflow: hidden`" - Will Po

Take a look on Will's great post about it:

https://medium.com/jsdownunder/locking-body-scroll-for-all-devices-22def9615177